# How to Calculate Probability of Multiple Events Occuring in an Extended Time Frame

Tags: statistics, time-series

There's an interesting question here: [Calculating probabilities over longer period of time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490859/calculating-probabilities-over-longer-period-of-time)

It discusses the probability of a single event occurring over an extended time frame.

I'd like to ask about how to calculate the probability of multiple occurrences of an event in an extended time frame. (Assuming the events are independent)

To adapt the previous question: instead of 1 fire in a month being a 5% chance, lets say 3 fires is a 5% chance.

How can I calculate the probability of 5 fires in 1 year?